# Supposedly Monero Adoption is picking up in the darknet markets. How does one verify this?

Tags: cryptocurrency-comparison

There are reports from news articles and other posts that Monero adoption is increasing in the darknet markets. How does one verify this? Is there a site that actually monitors which sites have favored monero adoption vs other payment methods?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I have been investigating the topic a while ago and created accounts on several markets listed on dark.fail or tor.taxi to have some direct overview. Most markets have been accepting BTC and XMR, one of them accepted also LTC and ZEC, however only transparent addresses. There have been some which switched to Monero-only dropping Bitcoin (and other coins) support entirely, amongst them WHM, the largest one at date but its admins retired after they reached their own goals (without any exit scam or such).

The only site I found which gives an overview without diving in yourself is darknetlive.com/markets/ where you can apply a filter "XMR" to list only those accepting Monero and you will see, only very few initially listed ones will disappear.

However, it's hard to scrape some more data from those markets, since they are all behind some custom / weird Captcha systems, so you can't really determine how much usage it has, especially on multi-coin marketplaces.

Disclaimer: Links are intended to be not clickable, if you want to do your research feel free to copy&paste.